# creating a reading list

Tags: phd, reading

Is the first time I write to this group and my question may be very basic (so I apologize). I'm getting ready to start my PhD and I'm collecting useful material for reading. I try to organize the list of articles and books I choose but I have a basic question. Once this material list is presented to my supervisors is it wrong then to make changes; I mean how it is possible to know from the beginning all the articles I will use the first period; Usually such lists are not created by reading in stages;

Thanks.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean. You want to develop a bibiographic search strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you asked your supervisors how they suggest you handle your reading?

My reading list is a folder in my reference manager that keeps changing as I discover new items, decide that I no longer need to read others, and have skimmed or read yet other items. It would be useless to stick to one list no matter what. In my case (I'm a postdoc) the reading list is mostly a reminder to myself. In your case it additionally serves to discuss your priorities with your supervisors who might already know some or most of the papers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. And yes, you are right, my list will help me to discuss and clarify my initial  priorities with my supervisors (with whom I have not talked about the format of the list yet). Thanks again.